# Add menu items to admin menu

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I am attempting to add several menu items to the Magento Admin area. The following code displays the "Local Access IPs" sub menu item, but not the "Remote Access Logs" sub menu item.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <menu>
    <VMR_Whitelist_menu translate="title" module="VMR_Whitelist">
        <title>VMR Modules</title>
        <sort_order>300</sort_order>
        <children>
            <!-- child items go here -->
            <subitem translate="title" module="VMR_Whitelist">
                <title>Remote Access Logs</title>
                <sort_order>9</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/whitelist/logs</action>
            </subitem>                
            <subitem translate="title" module="VMR_Whitelist">
                <title>Local Access IPs</title>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/whitelist/local</action>
            </subitem>
        </children>
    </VMR_Whitelist_menu>
 </menu>
  <acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <VMR_Whitelist_menu translate="title" module="VMR_Whitelist">
                    <title>VMR Modules</title>
                    <sort_order>300</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <!-- child items go here -->
                        <subitem translate="title" module="VMR_Whitelist">
                            <title>Remote Access Logs</title>
                            <sort_order>9</sort_order>
                        </subitem>
                        <subitem translate="title" module="VMR_Whitelist">
                            <title>Local Access IP Write Access</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </subitem>
                    </children>
                </VMR_Whitelist_menu>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

Any ideas on why one would show up and not the other are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Word, I wont add Magento to the front of my questions anymore, any chance you can tell me why that is bad practice? I may be able to apply that to something else in my life =]

Comment: I must agree with you, why was _magento_ removed from the question title? It makes the question sound a bit obscure without it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<subitem translate="title" module="VMR_Whitelist">
```

items name cann't be duplicated in one branch. Give another name for it. Like:

```
        <firstitem translate="title" module="VMR_Whitelist">
            <title>Remote Access Logs</title>
            <sort_order>9</sort_order>
            <action>adminhtml/whitelist/logs</action>
        </firstitem>                
        <seconditem translate="title" module="VMR_Whitelist">
            <title>Local Access IPs</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <action>adminhtml/whitelist/local</action>
        </seconditem>
```